# Getting only the insides of the source from the elastic search query

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

What im trying to do is to get only the source from the elastic search query in order to skip the processing on the javascript, so i could squize some more performance gains.Is it possible to do so?

So here is what i currenly do, i just get the data from the elastic search and iterate every one of those objects in order to construct an array that only contains the what's inside of _source:

```js
const { body } = await this.elsticSearchService.search<any>({
 index: this.configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX'),
 body: {
 query: {
    match_all: {},
    },
    size: 10000,
  },
});

const hits = body.hits.hits;

return hits.map((item: any) => item._source);
```

So my question is, is there a way to only get the _source from the  elastic search, in order
to skip the processing on the JavaScript?
So the object returned from the elastic search would look like this

```js
[
0:{ "key": "value"}, // key,value from _source object
1:{ "key": "value"}, // key,value from _source object
2:{ "key": "value"}, // key,value from _source object
]
```

so without all of the other fields like hits, took etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the structure of the response you get from the search call.

However, what you can do is to [specify `filter_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_common_parameters) so you only get the `_source` content in the response and you wouldn't need to process it since you know you only have _source content

```
const { body } = await this.elsticSearchService.search<any>({
 index: this.configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX'),
 filter_path: '**._source',         <--- add this line
 body: {
 query: {
    match_all: {},
    },
    size: 10000,
  },
});
```

Comment: ye, but I still need to "process it", since I'm iterating through every one of those objects to get the _source object inside of it in order to create an array of the real data

Comment: There's no other way, I'm sorry. You don't really need to process it, though, as you can just return hits.hits and then reference each _source object directly

Comment: That could work, just need to make some changes on the frontend. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Also know that when doing normal GET call to fetch a single document, you can get only the content of the _source, using [`getSource(...)`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_getsource)